# Determining big O notation for given function

Tags: algorithm, big-o

If I have a function such as `f(n) = 2/(1-(1/2)^n)`, can `O(f(n))`  be considered as `O(1)`? Or we cannot make that assumption. Note that `n` is a variable.

Comment: Can you please be more specific? Are you asking for the asymtotic complexity to compute 2/(1-(1/2)^n)?

Comment: @Jasper Updated it. Hope its more clear

Comment: Using `=` on big-Oh-notations will get you in trouble: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Equals_sign

Comment: I mean belongs to by that. Can you help?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it can.

The big-O notation states that `f(x)` is `O(g(x))` if `f(x) <= k*g(x)` for all `x > x_0`.

It is easy to see that `f(x) <= 3` for all `x > 1.585`. In this case, `k=3` and `x_0 = 1.585`.

[image: graph for f(n) = 2/(1-(1/2)^n)]

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can consider it O(1). The given function is a decreasing function. Hence you can find some n where the function is less than 1 and keep on decreasing. hence O(1) is Ok.